# No functions runs in the whole project (Google App Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

guys

Today faced up the problem - the whole project can't run any functions. Just show message "Running function [function name]" for infinite time. When i click "Cancel", GAS show me "An unexpected error occurred" message.

i've tried even plain functions, like

```
function do_smth() {
  var a = 1;
  var b = 3;
  var c = (b - a)*b + a;
}
```

Yesterday and even this night project worked correctly.
I checked other my projects - they work. I also duplicate this project and try to run. It didn't. But when create just new project from scratch - projects works.

So, one of my projects doesn't work at all. As well as its' copies.
But other and new projects - do.

What's a problem here?

Comment: Probably something in settings which you have not provided to us so hard to help, you should also provide more code, how do you know if the function you have here works when you only assign values and do nothing with vars? This function wont do anything for sure. You for sure need to add more info and debugging detail.

Comment: Anything under View > logs in the editor?

Comment: Try in another Google account.

Comment: Thank you all. It was some bug. Cause today project's working

Answer (score 0):

It was some bug.

At that moment, to solve problem i created new empty project and copied file by file all my project. And it works.